# Create custom ProgressBar drawable programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I need to change the color of my horizontal progressBar programmatically.
I need to set the progress bar with `color` and the background with `backgroundColor`
So I need to set a new progressDrawable to my progress bar or change the existing one.

The progress bar xml:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_stat_value"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_prog_bar_medium"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
```

The `CustomProgressBar` style:

```
<style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/height_progress_bar_medium</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/height_progress_bar_large</item>
</style>
```

The `custom_pogress_bar_horizzontal.xml` that I need to traduce:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I'm trying  with this code and I get only the background:

```
            val shape = GradientDrawable()
            shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
            shape.setColor(backgroundColor)

            pbStatValue.progressDrawable = shape
```

Answer (score 0):

I traduce this using the Drawable extensions:

translation of `<item android:id="@android:id/background">`

```kotlin
val item1 = GradientDrawable()
item1.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
item1.setColor(Utils.lighten(backgroundColor, 0.13))
```

translation of `<item android:id="@android:id/progress">`

```kotlin
val shape = GradientDrawable()
shape.setColor(color)
val item2 = ClipDrawable(shape, Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)
```

merge the Drawables:

```kotlin
val array = arrayOf(item1, item2)
val listDrawable = LayerDrawable(array)
```

assign it to the progress bar drawable

```kotlin
pbStatValue.progressDrawable = listDrawable
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.